# What is the best way to browse the contents of a jar file on the Mac platform?

Tags: java

What is the best way to browse the contents of a jar file on the Mac platform?

I usually use `unzip foo.jar -d foo`, but this is too slow with uber-jars.

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked on superuser? Anyway I'd suggest trying a TCMD/MC clone that can quick look into the zip.

Comment: no *unzip -l* on mac?

Comment: I am not a MAC user, but i have found some link in google for you, it seems that there is a Jar Explorer which does what you need, http://mac.softpedia.com/get/Developer-Tools/Jar-Explorer.shtml

Comment: What's an "*uber-jar*"?

Comment: As stated [in this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/321029/520458), `jar tf foo.jar` will list the contents of the jar. It's not *browsing*, though.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name typically one big jar that contains your own classes plus the contents of all the jars that they depend on (transitively).

Answer (score 3):

The [Better Zip Quicklook Generator](http://macitbetter.com/BetterZip-Quick-Look-Generator/) allows you to have a quick peek into jar archives. I like that for quick browsing in the finder. Currently it is free.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could install a IDE like eclipse or netbeans on ur Mac platform. These IDE tools will help you access the content of jar files easily.